# Is there widely accepted notion of tangent plane(or similar) for a vertex of a polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, 3d, tangent-line, polyhedra

For a vertex `v` of a polygon, I think it is reasonable to define its tangent line as `"a line passing through v, which is perpendicular to the angle bisecting line of angle v`"

But in 3d, it is difficult to generalize such notion.
Is there widely accepted notion of tangent plane or similar thing which is meaningful, useful, for a vertex of a polyhedron ?

Comment: If you can find the normal vector to that vertex, then the tangent plane is the plane perpendicular to that vector. As you know there isn't a proper definition of normal vector for a vertex but there are approximations in the average sense like in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_normal#:~:text=In%20the%20geometry%20of%20computer,faces%20that%20contain%20that%20vertex.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted!